# Consulta en sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Tengo una la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT
    A.IdDepartment,
    A.IdParent,
    A.Localidad,
    A.Codigo,
    A.Nombre,
    A.Departamento,
    A.Fecha
FROM VW_HORARIOS A
INNER JOIN VW_DAY_WORK B ON A.Codigo = B.Codigo AND A.Fecha = B.Fecha
GROUP BY A.IdDepartment,A.IdParent, A.Localidad, A.Codigo, A.Nombre, A.Departamento, A.Fecha, A.[Registro Entrada],A.[Registro Salida]
ORDER BY A.Fecha
```

pero quiero que me muestre solo los registros que estan en esta vista `VW_DAY_WORK` , ayuda

Comment: Porque utilizas el GROUP BY cuando no haces ninguna operación? eso funcionaria sin el group by como lo veo

Comment: No entiendo muy bien, pero puede ser `RIGHT JOIN` lo que buscas?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    B.*
FROM VW_HORARIOS A
INNER JOIN VW_DAY_WORK B ON A.Codigo = B.Codigo AND A.Fecha = B.Fecha
GROUP BY A.IdDepartment,A.IdParent, A.Localidad, A.Codigo, A.Nombre, A.Departamento, A.Fecha, A.[Registro Entrada],A.[Registro Salida]
ORDER BY A.Fecha
```

Comment: Edita la pregunta que esta todo ligado el codigo

Comment: no me da los resultados que necesito

Comment: Bueno si quieres los datos solo de B esa seria la manera, ahora si te esta dando un resultado que no es el que necesitas toca revisar el sql por lo que debes explicar que es lo que buscas obtener

Comment: Dejame Verificar que estoy en eso

Comment: Hola @AresXanderTolosaMorales esta pregunta se reporto como de "Baja calidad" , debes agregar una explicación del código, revisa [answer], saludos!

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT
    A.IdDepartment,
    A.IdParent,
    A.Localidad,
    A.Codigo,
    A.Nombre,
    A.Departamento,
    A.Fecha
FROM 
VW_HORARIOS A
RIGHT JOIN VW_DAY_WORK B ON A.Codigo = B.Codigo AND A.Fecha = B.Fecha
GROUP BY A.IdDepartment,A.IdParent, A.Localidad, A.Codigo, A.Nombre, A.Departamento, A.Fecha, A.[Registro Entrada],A.[Registro Salida]
ORDER BY A.Fecha
```

Comment: Hola Cristy Arturo, esta respuesta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad. Te recomiendo que leas [answer] y [¿Cómo darle formato a mis publicaciones utilizando Markdown o HTML?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) y edites tu publicación para mejorarla. Por ejemplo: dale formato al código para que se vea mejor y añade una descripción de lo que hayas cambiado y el motivo para el cambio. Saludos.